# Error passing array of ints to a plpgsql function (postgres 8.3.7)

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-8.3

I have the following function, which receives an array of ints, iterates it calling other function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculateAbsencesForIDs(INT[]) RETURNS TEXT AS 
'
DECLARE
  index integer := 0;
  resultArray decimal[];
  id int;
  result text;
BEGIN
  FOR id IN SELECT $1 LOOP

        resultArray[index] = calculateAbsenceForID(id); 
        index := index + 1;

END LOOP;
RETURN array_to_string(resultArray, result);
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I try to call it using:

```
SELECT calculateAbsencesForIDs(ARRAY[85,74,75,76,77,78,79,80]);
```

or

```
SELECT calculateAbsencesForIDs('{85,74,75,76,77,78,79,80}');
```

or

```
SELECT calculateAbsencesForIDs('{85,74,75,76,77,78,79,80}'::int[]);
...
```

But I have always the same error:

```
[Error Code: 0, SQL State: 22P02]  ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "{85,74,75,76,77,78,79,80}"
```

I don't know how I can call this function. I have looked in postgres docs, I think this is correct but it doesn`t work.

Comment: Starting with PostgreSQL 9.1 you can use [`FOREACH target IN ARRAY arr ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
FOR id IN SELECT $1 LOOP
```

means that you assign `id` to each value from `SELECT $1` which returns a single record with a single field of type `INT[]`.

As `id` is declared as `INT`, you get the conversion error you're observing.

In `8.4` and above you could use `UNNEST`, in `8.3` replace it with

```
FOR id IN
SELECT  $1[i]
FROM    generate_series(1, ARRAY_UPPER($1, 1)) i
LOOP
```

Alternatively, you could just do:

```
SELECT  ARRAY_TO_STRING
                (
                ARRAY
                (
                SELECT  calculateAbsenceForID($1[i])
                FROM    generate_series(1, ARRAY_UPPER($1, 1)) i
                )
                )
```

Comment: Wouldn't a for loop like this: `for i in 1 .. array_length($1, 1) loop` be better? (and use `$1[i]` inside the loop)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes, probably. Post it as an anwer, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the elements of the array like this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i in 1 .. array_length($1, 1) LOOP

        resultArray[i] = calculateAbsenceForID($1[i]); 

  END LOOP;
  RETURN array_to_string(resultArray, result);

END;
```

Note that this will throw an error if $1 is `NULL`